# Bigrock Domain Name Server - Google Cloud Platform Configuration

Tags: virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform

[image]I have successfully launched google cloud platform and I have got external IP address.

I have a registered domain name in BigRock.

I have got the below Domain Name servers from google.

```
   ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com
   ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com
   ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com
```

But, ping "hostname" is not working.

Is there any steps that manually connect DNS with ip Address .

Thanks,
Raja K

Comment: `dig ichase.biz.zone.ichase.biz` returns the IP `104.199.164.151`. I'm able to access http://ichase.biz.zone.ichase.biz/ (which 404s currently) just fine in the browser. I'm able to ping the hostname (and IP), too.

Comment: So, While i configuring Domain Name Server at Bigrock, What should I give ? should I give "ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com" OR "ichase.biz.zone.ichase.biz" ? Please suggest me.

Comment: The IP is actually a virtual machine external IP. Am I doing it right ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ip address of your domain to your Google dns servers.

Comment: Hi, I have added the IP. I have attached the screen shot too. Can you please suggest me what s wrong. Still my site is not reachable.